# TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I got a problem,
TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'NoneType'>.,
I don't know how to fix it...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGyQA.png)

Answer (score 0):

the image is not read correctly check the value given inside cv2.imread(),
the path should be for an image file example:

```
cv2.imread('/directory/subdirectory/file.jpg')
```